# Is it possible to send an e-mail addressed (BCC) to everyone that has sent me a message in a folder?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013

I have a folder of e-mails received from various people over the past year.

I'd like to send an e-mail out to every single person that has e-mailed me within this subfolder.

I'd prefer to send a single e-mail addressed to everyone, but so they cannot see each other's e-mail address.

Does anyone know how this can be done? I have figured out how to send a reply to every e-mail in the folder, but that would result in some people being spammed if they have e-mailed me multiple times over the years.

Many thanks

Comment: You should be able to do it with Outook's VBA

Comment: Can try with VBA as said which would be able to perform.

Comment: Approximately, how many senders do you have in that folder?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using either VBA script (quite complex) or by using two free tools in five steps:

1. Generate [Most Active Senders](https://www.outlookfreeware.com/en/products/all/OutlookStatisticsTopMessageSender/) report to gather all de-duplicated senders. Set large number of results (say, 10000) to collect all senders.
2. Copy-paste the resulting report to Excel (or other spreadsheet software).
3. In Excel, select the **Sender** column contents and copy it to the clipboard.
4. In Outlook, create a new message, write the text as required and paste copied previously senders to **To** field; then click the **Check Names** button on the Ribbon.
5. Run the [Send Messages Personally](https://www.outlookfreeware.com/en/products/all/OutlookMessagesSendPersonally/) utility to create a separate message for each of the recipients.

Please note that I recommend the mentioned tools because I'm one of the developers.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I exported the folder using Outlook's export to CSV file, and customised what was exported to only export the senders. I deduplicated it using an online javascript tool, and pasted it into the To: box.